# How do I embed Mercurial tags into my C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, mercurial, codeblocks

I would like to know if there is a way to embed Mercurial tags into my C/C++ code.

Basically I would like the tag string, which will end up being a release number (major.minor.rev), to be automatically inserted in a determined location of my C code as a static string.

The overall objective is that the application could be queried about its version number when executed with say a '-v' command line argument. Any alternative approach that doesn't involve trying to embed a Mercurial tag will be also welcomed as an answer.

I am using Code::Blocks on a Linux environment, so the solution can not rely on Visual Studio features.

Answer (score 6):

You will need the [keyword extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension) to allow expansion of keyword entries, it is bundled with mercurial.

For instance to get support for `$Id$` you could edit hgrc for you repo (`.hg/hgrc`) and add:

```
[extensions]
keyword =

[keyword]
# Enable expansion for the specific files
myfile.cpp =
# Enable for all .h files
**.h =
```

Then run

```
hg kwexpand
```

to expand keywords the relevant files, or

```
hg kwshrink
```

to shrink keywords. You can even create your own keywords by adding the `[keywordmaps]` entry, e.g.

```
[keywordmaps]
User = {author|user}
```

**Note**: This disables the builtin keywords

More details on the extension can be found [in the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension).

Answer (score 0):

We use a macro for this

```
#define CVS(a) static const volatile char *rcsid = a;

....
CVS("$Id$")
```

CVS automagically expands $Id$. I assume this is what mercurial tags work as well.

Then we can use the strings command to find the exact version of each file in the executable / library etc.

You could use something similar.

```
static const volatile char *rcsid = "$Id"; //or whatever mercurial tag you want

int main() {

    .....
    std::cout << "Version is " << rcsid << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If the $Id$ tag happened to have a stray `"` in it you would have trouble.  You might try `#define CVS(a)  static const volatile char *rcsid = #a;\  ... \  CVS($Id$);` instead.

Comment: @Tim Schaeffer, good catch, I posted from memory.  Sometimes there's no substitute for good old copy/paste

Comment: well now you have the problem of the Id tag having a stray comma in it.