# Writing Version Info into Comment Block

Tags: c, version-control, mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I embed Mercurial tags into my C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253953/how-do-i-embed-mercurial-tags-into-my-c-c-code)

Can I add version control info from Mercurial into the 1st comment block in the .c and .h files that the repo is tracking?

I assume it will involve adding something to the Makefile, such that a comment line in the source files gets substituted on each compilation with the latest version information

I have got as far as passing in a #define from the compiler (e.g. gcc -D) and have added the following to my Makefile:

```
HGVERSION:= $(shell hg parents --template 'hgid: {node|short}')
CFLAGS += -g -Wall -DHGVERSION="\"${HGVERSION}\""
```

but although this makes the preprocessor variable available to me, I'm not sure this helps with inserting some text into a comment block.

To elaborate, I can see how I can use HGVERSION to implement say a -ver flag to get the exe to printout its version info, but I can't see how to get that info into the actual text of the source files

To elaborate, I can see how I could use HGVERSION to implement some sort of programatic version information, e.g. printing the version when running the exe with a -ver flag or something like that, but not how I can get that info into the actual source file text in some way

I'd like to end up with something like this at the top of each of my src files:

```
/* some comments
 *
 * version x.y.z
 */
```

Am I on the right track or is some other technique required here?

Comment: I'm not sure it is an exact duplicate (I did find that same link to Mercurial wiki in my in my research). I'm trying to write it into a comment block in the source file, not use it programatically, i.e. not as a #define value used in a C statement.

Comment: Check the [Keyword](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) extension. But also read [Why You Don't Need It](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordPlan#head-2007fad6f31bf6f1f1b5c3d5b02e5c6225de3ec5).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I thought the same until yesterday when I realised we may have a use case where a customer gets some header files outside of any cloned repo (they just get a bunch of files) as they're not intersted in recompiling or doing any development. In this instance it would be useful (as a belt and braces approach) to be able to link the file they have to an update in our repo. Granted we should keep a record of exactly what we deliver and when, but as I say its a belt and braces thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with a simple `sed` or `awk` script.
Start each of your files with something distinctive, like:

```
/*
 * MERCURIAL VERSIONS HERE:
 */
```

Then write a script, which would add `* version $HGVERSION` just after this line.
The following `awk` script should do it:

```
awk -vHGVER=$HGVERSION '{print $0} /^  \* MERCURIAL VERSIONS HERE:$/ { print ' * ' HGVER}'
```

When do you run it?
If you add it to the makefile, it will run every time you compile. It can be OK, if you add some code to prevent adding the same version twice (`grep -v ... && awk ...`).